# Sorting arrays...can't seem to get it

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I need to write a program that will have a user enter a list of tutor names.  Only up to 10 peer tutors may be hired. Then, the program will present each name, based on a list alphabetized by last name. This is what I have so far. I've been figuring out how to sort array for hours and I just cant seem to figure it out. If anyone can explain to me in easy terms what I'm doing wrong, so I won't make the same mistakes again, I would appreciate it.

Here are the errors I'm getting:

```
 errors: PeerTutorReport.java:11: error: method tutorNames in class PeerTutorReport cannot be applied to       given types;
    int[] numTutors = tutorNames();
                      ^
required: int
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
PeerTutorReport.java:46: error: cannot find symbol
    String[] listNames = new String[numTutor];
                                    ^
 symbol:   variable numTutor
 location: class PeerTutorReport
  PeerTutorReport.java:48: error: cannot find symbol
    for (x = 0; x <= listNames.length; x++) {
         ^
  symbol:   variable x
 location: class PeerTutorReport
  PeerTutorReport.java:48: error: cannot find symbol
    for (x = 0; x <= listNames.length; x++) {
                ^
 symbol:   variable x
 location: class PeerTutorReport
 PeerTutorReport.java:48: error: cannot find symbol
    for (x = 0; x <= listNames.length; x++) {
                                       ^
 symbol:   variable x
  location: class PeerTutorReport
 PeerTutorReport.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
    numTutors[x] = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(" Tutor LAST NAME and FIRST NAME Listed in              Alphabetically Order"+(x+1)+ " " + "For example: 'Smith, John'");
              ^
```

Here's my code. My first method works no problem, but my second method... I'm having trouble with.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class PeerTutorReport {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] listNames = getTutorNames();
        int[] numTutors = tutorNames();
    }

    public static String[] getTutorNames() {
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        String[] listNames = new String[10];

        for (int x = 0; x < listNames.length; x++) {
            firstName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Tutor's First Name: ");
            lastName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Tutor's Last Name: ");
            listNames[x] = lastName + ", " + firstName;
        }
        return listNames;
    }

    public static String[] tutorNames(int numTutors) {
        String[] listNames = new String[numTutor];

        for (x = 0; x <= listNames.length; x++) {
            numTutors[x] = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                    "Tutor LAST NAME and FIRST  NAME Listed in Alphabetically Order"
                            + (x + 1) + " " + "For example: 'Smith, John'");
            Arrays.sort(listNames);
        }
        return listNames;
    }
}
```

Comment: what does your code actually do?  does it crash? does it sort wrong? does it not re-arrange the array at all?

Comment: [Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) might be easier to work with.
edit: nevermind, you already are working with this.

Comment: doesup do anything and im suppose to use arrays.sort

Comment: @AngieMckenzie what compiler error are you getting?

Comment: int[] numTutors = tutorNames();
                    ^
  required: int
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
PeerTutorReport.java:46: error: cannot find symbol
  String[] listNames = new String[numTutor];
                                  ^
  symbol:   variable numTutor
  location: class PeerTutorReport

Comment: @AngieMckenzie edit it into your question, you'll get better formatting that way

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: Let's look at the `main` method too:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] listNames = getTutorNames();
    int[] numTutors = tutorNames();
}
```

- You're not *using* the names that you've fetched in `getTutorNames`. Why ask for them if you're not going to pass them to anything else?
- The `tutorNames` method has an `int` parameter, but you're not passing any arguments
- The `tutorNames` method is declared to return a `String[]`, but you're trying to assign the result to an `int[]` variable.

Note that *none* of these problems are to do with sorting - they're much more basic than that. I suggest you stop and look *very closely* at all of your code.

---

EDIT: Okay, let's look at the other method:

```
public static String[] tutorNames(int numTutors) {
    String[] listNames = new String[numTutor];

    for (x = 0; x <= listNames.length; x++) {
        numTutors[x] = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("...");    
        Arrays.sort(listNames);
    }
    return listNames;
 }
```

You're trying to assign to `numTutors[x]` despite the fact that `numTutors` is an `int`. That's not going to work. Neither is `new String[numTutor]` as the `numTutor` variable doesn't exist.

You're also sorting the array (which is never populated) on every iteration... why?

---

EDIT: I wrote this answer before the question was corrected...

Well, here's the *first* problem:

```
for (int x = 0; x < listNames.length; x++) {
    firstName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Tutor's First Name: ");
    lastName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Tutor's Last Name: ");
}
```

You're asking for 10 pairs of names... but just storing them in the `firstName` and `lastName` variable each time. Your `listNames` variable is never touched. You probably want something like:

```
for (int x = 0; x < listNames.length; x++) {
    String firstName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Tutor's First Name: ");
    String lastName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Tutor's Last Name: ");
    listNames[x] = lastName + ", " + firstName;
}
```

Note how I've moved the variable declarations for `firstName` and `lastName` inside the loop - you're not using them outside the loop anyway, so there's no benefit in declaring them earlier. In general, prefer to restrict the scope of local variables as far as you can.

Or just ask for a single name per tutor:

```
for (int x = 0; x < listNames.length; x++) {
    listNames[x] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Tutor's Name: ");
}
```

Comment: oh wow, i had that in my program but i forgot to copy and paste that part for some reason

Comment: @AngieMckenzie: I don't know what you mean. You copied and pasted the code which asked for the names - but you didn't use that data to populate `listNames`. I can't see how this is an *omission* of copy/paste...

Comment: @JonSkeet some people "copy and paste" their code in mysterious ways

Comment: i deleted some stuff before i copy and paste the program. i took off some of the code off and comments like if user enter invalid input, so i must have deleted it by accident

Comment: @AngieMckenzie: Anything else you want to change about the question? I'd rather not point out the next mistake only to hear that you'd actually already fixed that.

Comment: no.. that wasnt even the question. my question is how to fix the sorting method. the first method is fine. i never had priblem with it. it compile by it self. the 2nd method which is the public static String[] tutorNames(int numTutors). im having trouble with that. im not even sure if i set up the whole method correctly

Comment: @AngieMckenzie: Actually, I've added a couple of points about the `tutorNames` method.

Comment: @AngieMckenzie: So why would you *break* a method which was already working? Basically there are *lots* of things wrong with this code at the moment. I'm not entirely sure it's worth going through them one at a time - your compiler should be pointing out the various compile-time errors to you.

Comment: @AngieMckenzie: Okay, I've added another edit about the brokenness of `main` - but as I say, I really think you ought to take a good hard look at this from scratch. You need to think about where you want to get data, and where you want to pass it.

Comment: what do u mean break a method? i didnt break anything

Comment: @AngieMckenzie: Yes you did - you removed the assignment to `listNames[x]` within `getTutorNames`, which made the method useless. (It would always return an array of empty references.)

Comment: i just remove thing that arent necessary... like COMMENTs. why would that even matter.

Comment: ok you're right but that was by mistake and it wasnt even the question im asking. i even stated the question

Comment: @AngieMckenzie: "i deleted some stuff before i copy and paste the program. i took off some of the code off and comments like if user enter invalid input, so i must have deleted it by accident" - you removed a very important line of code, which was the source of my whole original answer. By doing that, you wasted my time and the time of anyone else looking at the question. My point is that you need to be careful.

Comment: @AngieMckenzie: You claim the question is about sorting, but your code is broken well before you get to the sorting part. How are we meant to spot the difference between code which was accidentally broken through carelessness, and code that has never worked?

Comment: ...ok sorry. im just frustrated. i've been trying to get this sorting method to work

Comment: @AngieMckenzie: I suggest you start from scratch and try to get *very* clear in your head what each method is meant to do. Do you want your `tutorNames` method to both ask for the names *and* sort them? If so, why call `getTutorNames()` first? If not, why are you asking for the names again within `tutorNames`?

Comment: i want the the name to be sorted by last name. for an example like this Smith, John. that was the part im getting confused with

Comment: @AngieMckenzie: No, it really wasn't. Your code shows large amounts of confusion which have nothing to do with sorting. Get rid of the sorting call and your code will still be completely broken. You need to get everything *apart* from the sorting working first... then you can fix the sorting.

Comment: public static String[] tutorNames(String[] listNames)

Comment: @AngieMckenzie: That's a good start, yes. Although I'd call it `sortNames`, as that's what it's meant to do.

Comment: am i suppose to declare the method in the main method?

Comment: @AngieMckenzie: No... why would you? What would that even mean?

Comment: like String[] sortNames = getSortNames(listNames); ... ok nvm

Comment: @AngieMckenzie yes, you would do that in the `main` method.  Most people refer to that as "calling" the method.

Comment: @AngieMckenzie: That's *calling* the method. The *declaration* of the method is the `public static String[] tutorNames(String[] listNames)` part. (But I wouldn't call it `getSortNames` either - it's just going to sort the array, so call it `sortNames`.)

Comment: ok thanks, sorry for putting up with me. im a beginner and still trying to learn. and u've been a big help so far.

Comment: is this right so far ?                                                              public static String[] sortTutorNames(String[] listNames) {
    
                               
  String[] sortNames = new String[listNames];

Comment: String[] sortNames = sortTutorNames(listNames); this is mine calling method

Comment: @AngieMckenzie: Sorry, Stack Overflow really isn't suitable for the sort of interactive debugging you're trying to do. But no, the first line of your `sortTutorNames` method wouldn't even compile, so it can't be right.

Comment: god i just dont get it. so public static String[] sortNames(String[] listNames) as my method

Comment: how would i name my method calling? String[] sortNames(); ?

Comment: @AngieMckenzie: Sorry, I'm done with this question - while this site is great for specific problems, it's not a good way to learn a language in general. You should consult a book, tutorial, or teacher (in person).

Answer (score 0):

Well for one thing it looks like your return type on your tutorNames function is a string array, but you are trying to assign it in main() to an int array variable.

Comment: to be honest. im not really sure what im doing to sort it alphabetically as i have never done it before

Comment: @AngieMckenzie: Your problems don't seem to have anything to do with sorting at the moment, to be honest - they're before you even get to the sorting.

Comment: wait huh? the first method i created works perfectly as what i want it to do. the 2nd method is where the problem comes in. im getting errors. i know my set up for the sorting method is wrong obviously. i just dont know what to do

Comment: You're redefining String[] listNames in every function, so it's falling out of scope and not retaining its values after they get set.  In the function that actually performs the sort, you will be sorting an array with no contents because of this.

Comment: what am i suppose to do? change the function name for the sort method? im not sure what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just throwing this out there, because I can't make sense of the `int[] numTutors = tutorNames()` line, but try the following

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    String[] listNames = getTutorNames();
    Arrays.sort(listNames);
    for(int i=0; i<listNames.length; i++)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(listNames[i]);
    }
}
```

assuming that `String[] listNames = getTutorNames();`, executed correctly, It should correctly sort your names. and then display them.

Comment: iam is this right?  public static String[] sortTutorNames(String[] listNames) { String[] sortNames = new String[listNames];

Comment: String[] sortNames = sortTutorNames(listNames); this is mine calling method –

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to do your homework for you, but this would be a better way to form your program, in pseudo-code:

```
public class Whatever {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int desiredListSize = 10;
        String[] listNames = getTutorNames(intDesiredListSize);

        // if you display the list of names right now,
        // they should be in the order the user entered them
        displayListOfNamesToUser(listNames);

        // now sort the array
        Arrays.sort(listNames);

        // now display it again, it should be sorted
        displayListOfNamesToUser(listNames);
    }

    public static String[] getTutorNames(int numberOfInputs) {
        String firstName, lastName;
        String[] names = new String[numberOfInputs];
        for (int x = 0; x < numberOfInputs; x++) {
            firstName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Tutor's First Name: ");
            lastName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Tutor's Last Name: ");
            listNames[x] = lastName + ", " + firstName;
        }
        return names;
    }

    public void displayListOfNamesToUser(String[] names) {
        for (int x = 0; x < names.length; x++) {
            //display names[x]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why do u have int numberOfInputs?

Comment: would it not be store in "listNames"   String[] listNames = new String[10];

Comment: Having arbitrary constant values (like 10) isn't something you should make a habit of.  If you're going to have them, either declare them as constants in your class or at least throw them somewhere that's obvious instead of buried in one of your functions.  Putting it in main() was just an attempt on my part to show that you could break that out into a configurable value.  Ideally you'd make it a parameter of your main as one of the args[] and accept that as an input for the number of names you wanted to record.

Comment: i see, that what i was trying to do i think with int numTutors = 0;